# Microsoft Excel - Transform text type of cell to a numeric cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to tranform multiples text cells (with numbers in it), to numeric type of cells. To finally manipulate the numbers

Comment: https://www.google.no/search?q=Microsoft+Excel+-+Transform+text+type+of+cell+to+a+numeric+cell&oq=Microsoft+Excel+-+Transform+text+type+of+cell+to+a+numeric+cell&aqs=chrome..69i57.450j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @boblet That isn't the way SU wants you to respond to simple questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5280/embrace-the-non-googlers

Comment: I stand corrected, I beg your pardon.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of methods.  Here's the best I've heard:

- Put the value zero in a spare cell
- Copy that cell
- Select the text cells you want to transform
- Use paste special and select Add, Values

If you learn to use the keyboard, this takes a fraction of a second.